# How can I change the text of the back button on this dropdown pie chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When you click on the 'Recycled Materials' section of the pie chart it drops down into more info about that section.

The problem is the back button has the default text 'Back to Brands' in it and I can't find anywhere in my code to change that.

My code is as follows:

Java:

```
 $(function () {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Green Up Amount Recycled'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the Recycled Materials slice for more information.'
    },
   plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: "Landfill - 45,821 lbs",
            y: 23.73,
        }, {
            name: "Recycled Materials - 147,276 lbs",
            y: 76.27,
            drilldown: "Recycled Materials"
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: "Recycled Materials",
            id: "Recycled Materials",
            data: [
                ["Tent Frames and Chairs - 6,400 lbs", 4.35],
                ["Aluminum Cans - 28,950 lbs", 19.66],
                ["Plastic PET Bottles - 36,420 lbs", 24.73],
                ["Glass - 40,950 lbs", 27.8],
                ["Cardboard - 30,000 lbs", 20.37],
                ["Solo Cups - 4,556 lbs", 3.09],
            ]
        }]
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; max-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
name: "Brands"
```

to whatever you have, maybe "Materials", [example](http://jsfiddle.net/980tmeae/)